# length of a decimal number

Tags: sql

```
select length('10.2') from dual;
```

I want to know the length of the number 10.2 which is 3, but in the above query it is showing 4.

What is the right query?

Comment: each of `1`,`0`,`.`,`2` is a character. so the length is 4.

Comment: Length is generally going to indicate the number of characters, which is 4 in the code you provided and should be correct.

Comment: You don't specify which SQL software you're using but I suspect it's giving you the length of the _string_.

Comment: `'10.2'` is a string literal, not a numeric literal.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly do that. You'll have to first convert the string to pure numeric value (remove even the decimal point). You can try the following snippet in T-SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intAlpha INT
    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
    BEGIN
        WHILE @intAlpha > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
            SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
        END
    END
    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
;
```

Once your function is ready, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT len(fn_GetNumeric('10.2'))
```

Comment: This answer is assuming you use MS SQL. There is no equivalent for PATINDEX in MySQL as far as I know..

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, please mark it as an answer and upvote :)

Comment: thanks sujeet.plz help me on this..in my table(A) one column(cost) is of varchar2(30), and to which it inserts data (table B, column **cost1**)is of type number(10,2).

when I check ---
select sum(cost1) from B...it is showing error message --ORA-01722: invalid number-----

how can I find the error here

Comment: you can always create a new question for answers.. however can you share a sample value list along with the query used? helps in understanding the issue!

Comment: select * from A;

it has a column named cost and it is of varchar(30).it has data like 100,300.99,777,765,
 but when i go for 
select sum(COST) from A;
 it is showing invalid number...

Comment: I could have earned some reputation points had this been a separate question.. anyways, the query you want is SELECT SUM(CAST(COST AS DECIMAL(10,2))) FROM A

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding.  `length()` is a function that operators on strings.  The argument is a string which has four characters '1', '0', '.', and '2'.  Hence, the returned value is "4".

There is no number in your query.  And "the length of a number" doesn't make sense, because length is defined only for strings (and various large binary objects, depending on the database).

I'm not sure what you are looking for to get "3", so I can't make a suggestion for that.

Comment: hi Gordon..thanx fr ur feedback